# openGL context in console

Tags: opengl, console, openglcontext

I'd like to use certain functions of openGL, but nothing related to rendering visual content. Is there way to create it without ANY dependencies (not to windows, nor some package[SDL, SFML, GLUT])? Only libraries allowed are those without external libraries, just like GLEW which I use.

Comment: What functions of OpenGL would be useful without a context? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: computing with shaders, projections, many things actually.. Please don't suggest me to use CUDA or program it by myself, ofcourse that's possibility but I want to know if that can be done (and the less code for doing so, the better

Comment: I don't understand your use of the term "external libraries". GLEW does not work without the WGL and GLX functions, which are just as external as Win32 or X11. Indeed, Win32 _provides_ WGL functions, just as X11 provides the GLX functions. So the same logic that prevents you from using FreeGLUT or GLFW would also prevent you from using GLEW.

Comment: It's hardly defined by other words. I mean that I need something that you just include and that's all.  In case of glew you just include glew and it takes care of everything, however for example using SFML you need to have somewhere arround external dynamic librarie.

Comment: @Raven FreeGLUT and GLFW both have static builds, if you are allergic to DLLs. Also, that doesn't explain how having a dependency "to windows" is somehow possible, given that Windows is necessary to make GLEW work.

Comment: You *will* need a context when you want to use shaders. Use WGL_ARB_create_context/GLX_ARB_create_context for that.

Comment: @Nicolas Bolas Ok then probably more suitable question. What is the lightest cross-platform library that can staticaly link and can create context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the lightest cross-platform library that can staticaly link and can create context.

How do you define "lightest?"

The two cross-platform libraries that do the least other than creating OpenGL windows are [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) and [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/).

FreeGLUT has about a 5.2MB distribution (after unzipping), while GLFW has a 2.6MB distro. Does that make it "lighter"? FreeGLUT's compiled static library, in release mode under VS2008, is around 500KB; the one for GLFW under similar compilation is 120KB. Does that make it "lighter"?

Comment: why are you asking me? I don't know if the size is making library lighter. It might seem so, it might not be true... that's why I'm asking here. Ofcourse I could just use glut and be alright, but I wanted to ask here if there's something I don't know about aswell as your personal opinion because you might be much more skilled than me.

Comment: @Raven I'm asking you because the word "lighter" is entirely subjective. There is no objective standard for what is "heavy" or "light". My personal opinion is... I wouldn't care. I would only care about "light" or "heavy" libraries if what I'm trying to do explicitly requires a small executable. What **I** care about is quality of documentation, ease of use, and overall solid functionality.

Comment: You got good point, it's very subjective and depends on what I'm just doing. At last I've chosen SFML because I realized that it's functionality is separated into 5 libraries and one I need - window has just 56 kb. Creating context is also just a matter of one line. I know stack overflow should be used for finding answer for specific question, but I find many times it's better at pointing me in right direction.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is known in general as off-screen rendering. In theory it is possible perfectly well, however the practical implementation has a lot of caveats. Most importantly on all major high performance implementations: Even if no rendering window is visible you still need the graphics system running and being active and your program run in the environment of this graphics system.

On Windows the most straightforward way to go is creating invisible window, just a window you create with *CreateWindowEx* but not map with *ShowWindow*; you don't even need a event processing loop for that. In this window you create your OpenGL context as usual, but instead of rendering to the window framebuffer, you render to a Frame Buffer Object.

On X11/GLX it's even more straightforward: X11/GLX offers PBuffers without extensions (Windows has PBuffers, too, but for creating one you need a regular OpenGL context first). So on X11 you can create a PBuffer without a proxy window. The PBuffer iteself can be rendered to as off-screen buffer; Frame Buffer Object work in a PBuffer, as well, if the implementation supports them. Using a invisible window with a Frame Buffer Object, just like  with Windows, works as well. Either way, with current drivers X11 must be active and the bound console, so you can *not* start an additional X server in the background and have your off-screen rendering happen there, but this is just a limitation of the drivers and not of X11, GLX or OpenGL.

> Only libraries allowed are those without external libraries, just like GLEW which I use.

You can link GLEW statically to your program. If you're hardcore you can do extension loading manually, but why would you want to do that?